# How does the Bedroll Deadzone work in 7 Days to Die?

Tags: 7-days-to-die

My friends and I have taken up residence in a large hospital. We've cleared out a few floors of debris and junk, put our bedrolls and workshops down, and got to work.

I've closed off a majority of the hospital as well, since we don't have any use for it, however zombies are spawning in those closed off areas, slowly breaking down the concrete walls, and coming for us. We have the Bedroll Deadzone set to the max for the server (50 blocks I think), but this hasn't helped much.

I'm wondering how exactly the deadzone works. Is it possible to set up a number of bedrolls in various places ~50 blocks apart? The bedroll I place seems to be my active spawn point, so I would theoretically set up a bunch of bedrolls throughout the hospital, and then set my final one where I want to respawn. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So bedrolls do not appear to work in this way. The only bedroll that applies a deadzone is the one you will spawn at, which is the final bedroll that you place down.